# access function arguments from function decorator

Tags: python

If I have a function that looks like:

```
@app.route('/categories/id/<int:id>/edit')
@login_required
def edit_category(id):
   #some code...
```

And the login_required decorator looks like this

```
def login_required(f):
   @wraps(f)
   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
       print id #given to edit_category by app.route decorator
       return f(*args, **kwargs)
   return wrapper
```

How do I access the id variable that is given to edit_category as an argument by the app.route decorator, from the login_required decorator?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The positional arguments to the wrapper function come in the `args` (first argument - `*args` ) , and the keyword arguments for the method come in `kwargs` (second argument - `**kwargs` ).

`args` is a tuple , where the first element refers to the first positional argument, second element is the second positional argument.

`kwargs` is a dictionary , where the key is the keyword (for the argument) and the value is the value passed in for that keyword.

Example -

```
>>> def decor(func):
...     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
...             print('args - ',args)
...             print('kwargs - ',kwargs)
...             return func(*args, **kwargs)
...     return wrapper
...
>>> @decor
... def a(*a, **b):
...     print("In a")
...     print(a)
...     print(b)
...
>>> a(1,2,x=10,y=20)
args -  (1, 2)
kwargs -  {'y': 20, 'x': 10}
In a
(1, 2)
{'y': 20, 'x': 10}
```

You can test whether `app.route` is sending `id` as positional argument or keyword argument by printing both `args` and `kwargs` and take the correct value. I think it may be coming in as positional argument, if so, it would be the first element of `args` .

Comment: It seems to be a Flask question but it's hard to say. It helped me as a Django user anyway and I found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request) that in this case `id` would be a keyword argument.